# Объединения (пример из сетевого программирования)

Tags: c, объединение, сетевое-программирование

Я, видимо, не совсем понимаю, как работают `union` в `Си`, поэтому просьба прокомментировать мои вопросы по следующему небольшому коду. (Чтобы сократить код, приведу только функцию `main()`)

```
int main(void)
{
    int sockfd; 
    socklen_t size = 2000;

    union {
       struct sockaddr sa;
       char mas[2000];
    }un;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)un.mas,&size);
    printf("%d\n\n", un.sa.sa_family);


    return 0;
}
```

1) Я ведь даже не заполняю структуру `struct sockaddr sa`, почему `printf()` печатает правильный ответ?

2) Если я вместо `union` напишу `struct`, то ответ будет неправильный.

3) Если переменные не будут находиться в `union` или `struct`, то вылезает предупреждение `sa.sa_family’ is used uninitialized in this function`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

Comment: Формулировка вопроса говорит о том, что вы даже и не пытались поинтересоваться тем, что такое union. Может начать надо с этого?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Неудобный пример.
Представьте что у вас есть юнион:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
     int value; // 4 байта
    };
    struct {
     char a; // 1 байт
     char b; // 1 байт
     char c; // 1 байт
     char d; // 1 байт
    };
} Test;
```

Первое поле - int - объединяет в себе последующие char поля. В этом концепция union-ов. Вот трейс:

```
Test test;  
test.value = 0; // value = { 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 }
test.a = 1;     // value = { 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 }
test.b = 2;     // value = { 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000001 }
test.c = 3;     // value = { 00000000 00000011 00000010 00000001 }
test.d = 4;     // value = { 00000100 00000011 00000010 00000001 }
```

Видно, что меняя одно из мелких char полей меняется и большое int поле с именем value. По сути, наш union - это int число, но, для удобства, мы разделили это число на 4 байта a,b,c,d. Можем работать как со всеми 4 байтами сразу - value, так и с каждым отдельным байтом - a,b,c,d.

В вашем случае всё аналогично. Есть struct sockaddr sa, далее, его представляют как массив из char длинной в 2000 байт.

1.) Заполняете.

```
getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)un.mas,&size); // передаёте указатель на начало массива char.Данные пишутся туда, как видно из моего примера с int числом, заполняя a,b,c,d мы меняем value. Здесь так же. Заполняя массив, мы меняем sa.
```

2.) И это логично, структура - это структура, юнион - это юнион. Не путайте их.

3.) Неужели даже так не получается?

```
struct sockaddr sa;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sa,&size);
printf("%d\n\n", sa.sa_family);
```

Comment: Вот только юнион плохо объявлен. Если поменть a, то b,c,d будут иметь то же значение

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо за замечание, про offset-ы в сях уже забыл

Comment: У меня тогда еще пару вопросов к Вам:
1) Если в union первый член будет - char a, а второй член - int b, то при присваивании переменной b = 1000,  что будет записано в a? максимально допустимое значение типа char?

Comment: 2) Если принять, что 1 байт = 4 бита, тогда я понимаю, почему 
value = { 0000 0000 0000 0001 } при а = 1.
Но почему при b = 2, value = { 0100 0011 0010 0001 }, разве не должно быть так
 value = { 0000 0000 0010 0001 }? 
Или я что-то не так понял...?

Comment: @ЕгорФилатов >>Если принять, что 1 байт = 4 бита<< В любом курсе информатики байт = 8 бит. Если это цифровая техника работающая от электрического тока, то всегда принемайте что 1 байт = 8 бит. Я не писал пустые нолики слева потому что посчитал это избыточным...

Comment: @ЕгорФилатов >> при присваивании переменной b = 1000, что будет записано в a? << в b будет 00000000 00000000 00000011 11101000, соответственно, в а будет хвост: "11101000"